# Meteor 1.3 - running meteor test throws AssertionError: "undefined" === false

Tags: meteor

I've just upgraded an existing Meteor 1.2 project to Meteor 1.3 and would like to start using the new "meteor test" function.
However, when I run the command `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha` I get the output below.

Can anyone point me in the direction on how to narrow down the cause of this. The only related issue I could find was [issue #6527 import-scanner - inconsistent lazy loading package files in Meteor 1.3-rc.3](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6527), however this is marked as resolved.

Many thanks in advance for any clues!

```
[[[[[ Tests ]]]]]                             

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

/home/me/.meteor/packages/coffeescript/.1.0.15.1v9es4z++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:116
  throw error;
        ^
AssertionError: "undefined" === false
    at ImportScanner._combineFiles (/tools/isobuild/import-scanner.js:154:12)
    at /tools/isobuild/import-scanner.js:140:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ImportScanner.addInputFiles (/tools/isobuild/import-scanner.js:119:11)
    at /tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:756:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.computeJsOutputFilesMap (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:726:19)
    at ClientTarget._emitResources (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:910:8)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:677:12
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ClientTarget.make (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:668:18)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2509:14
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2599:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.0_3.61500n++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2598:7
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2490:31)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:591:36
    at Function.run (/tools/tool-env/profile.js:489:12)
    at bundleApp (/tools/runners/run-app.js:581:34)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:634:35)
    at AppRunner._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:887:28)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:411:12
```

Answer (score 2):

By a process of brute force elimination (removing all files from the project and adding them back, one by one!), I discovered that the problem is being triggered by the presence of the `bootstrap-settings.json` file which is used to manage the bootstrap files generated by the `huttonr:bootstrap3` package

I have raised an issue regarding this directly with the project owner: https://github.com/huttonr/bootstrap3/issues/17

In the meantime, as a workaround I have disabled the `huttonr:bootstrap3` package and removed the `client/stylesheets/bootstrap-settings.json` file

Comment: I filed a similar issue too for Meteor 1.3.2. It's been flagged `help-wanted`